# nested loop array reference in perl

Tags: perl

i have 2 files with the same rows in this format

for example

file 1

```
string1:string2:string3
string4:string6:string6
string7:string8:string9
```

file2

```
string1:string2:string3
string4:string6:string6
string7:string8:string9
```

i have to do some works with this files, but i'm at the beginning on write, so first of all i made this

```
foreach my $firstFileString(<FILE1>){
    my @firstArray = split(/:/,$firstFileString);
    foreach my $secondFileString(<FILE2>){
    my @secondArray = split(/:/,$secondFileString);
    print "$firstArray[0]\n";
    }
}
```

*before continuing on the program , i incurred in this problem by output, in this row `print "$firstArray[0]\n";`  i' m getting always `string1`*. I'm expecting `string1, string4,string7`

how is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program prints `string1` for each line of `file2` the *first* time it is read.

When the inner loop exits, and the outer loop goes on to read the second line of `file1`, the file handle `FILE2` is already at end of file, so there is nothing more to be read and the inner loop is never entered again.

The best way to fix this is to open `file2` *inside* the outer loop, so that it is always at the start of the file when you want to read through it. It is also best to use lexical file handles (`$file1` instead of `FILE1`) and to read a file using `while`, which reads files one line at a time, instead of `foreach`, which reads the *whole file* and then loops over the in-memory lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $file1, '<', 'file1.txt';

while (my $line1 = <$file1>) {
  chomp $line1;
  my @fields1 = split /:/, $line1;

  open my $file2, '<', 'file2.txt';

  while (my $line2 = <$file2>) {
    chomp $line2;
    my @fields2 = split /:/, $line2;

    print "$fields1[0]\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
string1
string1
string1
string4
string4
string4
string7
string7
string7
```

---

**Update**

An alternative method, as you correctly say, is to read the whole of `file2` into an array. That way you don't have to reopen and read through the file several times.

Since you're storing the data in memory, you may as well split it into fields as well, to save doing that several times. This program shows how. `file2` is read into array `@file2`, each element of which is an array of fields.

Now all the inner loop has to do is to set `$fields2` to each row of the array. It's an array *reference*, so the fields are `$fields2->[0]`, `$fields2->[1]` etc.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;


open my $fh2, '<', 'file2.txt';

my @file2;
while (<$fh2>) {
  chomp;
  push @file2, [ split /:/ ];
}

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1.txt';

while (my $line1 = <$fh1>) {
  chomp $line1;
  my @fields1 = split /:/, $line1;

  for my $fields2 (@file2) {
    print "$fields1[0]\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: you sir, always save my day. One question , do you think another way to resolve is to do that before looping -> `my @array = <FILE2>` ? and then loops...

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: I'm glad to help. Yes, you could do that. If you're going that way then you should also split the lines into fields and store it as an array of arrays.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: I've added to my solution to show how.

Comment: why you used `chomp` in this case?

Comment: Because each line read from a file will have a line terminator - a newline - at the end. Without the `chomp`, the last field from `split` will keep the newline, which I'm pretty certain you don't want.

Comment: is there any differences between `chomp;` or `chomp($argument);` ?

Comment: Your question reminded me that I forgot to `chomp` in all the other loops. Sorry if that confused you.

Comment: Sheesh. Yes, I'm sorry - I'm trying to edit Perl on an Android tablet! `chomp` without an argument is the same as `chomp $_`. In this case they should all have arguments. I'll fix it.

Comment: i'm making a new question can you respond on that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you read FILE2 to the end the first time through the outer loop.  The second time through the outer loop, it's at the end of the file, so this code:

```
foreach my $secondFileString(<FILE2>){
```

Does nothing.  If you want FILE2 to read again, you can close and open it in the loop, or seek back

```
foreach my $firstFileString(<FILE1>){
    my @firstArray = split(/:/,$firstFileString);
    seek FILE2, 0, SEEK_SET;
    foreach my $secondFileString(<FILE2>){
    my @secondArray = split(/:/,$secondFileString);
    print "$firstArray[0]\n";
    }
}
```

Though the output from that would be

```
string1
string1
string1
string4
string4
string4
string7
string7
string7
```

since you're printing within the inner loop and every thing is triplicated as a result.  Perhaps you meant to print in the outer loop, before the iteration over `FILE2`?